# Sequelize - return object from 2nd level chain after last callback execution is complete

Tags: callback, promise, sequelize.js, graphql-js

in the addBussiness method, I create a business object and then use the result to create a UserBusiness object in the database using sequelize.

I want to return the Business object created after the UserBusiness object is done creating.

As it stands now I think due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript, the business object is returned before the UserBusiness object is done creating.

Is there a way to return the object from the 1st callback in the 2nd callback?

```
addBusiness(_,args) {
      // this is needed to put it correctly in the geometry point format that the database expects
      var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [args.input.location.longitude,args.input.location.latitude] }; 
      args.input.location = point;

      return Business.create(args.input, {
        include: [{
          association: Hours,
          as: 'hours'
        }]
      }).then(business => {
        UserBusiness.create({userId: args.input.userId, businessId: business.businessId})
        return business; // this might get returned before UserBusiness.create is done executing
      })
    },
```

here is my mapping defined in sequelized:

```
UserAccountModel.belongsToMany(BusinessModel, { through: UserBusinessModel, foreignKey: 'user_id'});
BusinessModel.belongsToMany(UserAccountModel, { through: UserBusinessModel , foreignKey: 'business_id'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `UserBusiness` object after creation and then return `UserBusiness.bussiness` or save business object in a variable and return the variable after `UserBusiness` object is created.

```
addBusiness(_,args) {
      var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [args.input.location.longitude,args.input.location.latitude] }; 
      args.input.location = point;

      return Business.create(args.input, {
        include: [{
          association: Hours,
          as: 'hours'
        }]
      }).then(business => {
        return UserBusiness.create({userId: args.input.userId, businessId: business.businessId})
      }).then(UserBusiness => {
        return UserBusiness.business;
      })
    }
```

**OR**

```
addBusiness(_,args) {
  var _business;
  var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [args.input.location.longitude,args.input.location.latitude] }; 
  args.input.location = point;

  return Business.create(args.input, {
    include: [{
      association: Hours,
      as: 'hours'
    }]
  }).then(business => {
    _business = business;
    return UserBusiness.create({userId: args.input.userId, businessId: business.businessId})
  })
   .then(() => {
     return _business;
  })
}
```

Comment: I just tried both options and they didnt work. just returned null

Comment: Pretty sure the first option should work. Just to confirm are you sure that `business `or `userBusiness` object is being created?  Did you try logging both objects after creation? Also, add a `catch` block after last `then` to see if there are any errors

Comment: yes I can confirm that I see in the Database that both Business and UserBusiness object are created. it is a many to many relationship as defined by sequelize. I'ved edited the OP to include my mapping definiton